# Laravel 5.5 - dynamically adding route suffixes causes 'Page has expired'?

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5.5

For various reasons too long to go into, we're trying to create a route structure such that every route also dynamically recognizes itself with a `-mobile` suffix. For example, if we have `/login` defined in our routes, the user can also automatically navigate to `/login-mobile` for a version of `/login` with the header and footer removed.

We've had a degree of success setting this up in the render function of `/app/Exceptions/Handler.php`, catching and rerouting just before it throws a 404 error.

```
public function render( $request, Exception $exception ) {
    $suffix = '-mobile';
    $route = $request->getPathInfo();

    // Check for mobile page suffix
    if ( substr( $route, -strlen( $suffix ) ) === $suffix && strpos( $route, '/api' ) === false ) {
        define( 'MOBILE_PAGE', true );
        $route = substr( $route, 0, -strlen( $suffix ) );
        $new_request = $request->duplicate();
        $new_request->server->set( 'REQUEST_URI', $route );

        return \Route::dispatch( $new_request );
    }

    return parent::render( $request, $exception );
}
```

In short, if it detects a route that ends in `-mobile`, it serves a duplicate of the request with `-mobile` removed. Otherwise, it processes the route as normal. This is functional and working great.

Except... when we submit a form and it passes through a `-mobile` route, it invariably returns a "Page has expired" error, and ignores the form submission. This immediately indicates an issue with the CSRF token not being sent in the request - but the normal version of the page works fine, and we're directly duplicating the raw request. A `var_dump( $new_request );` shows the inputs, headers, cookies, session ID, everything as identical. So why does Laravel throw this error?

Can anyone can shed some light on this issue, or illuminate a simpler way to dynamically suffix all routes?

Comment: This is actually a middleware job since putting on exception, the framework expects response already built. Set it before `VerifyCsrfToken` verifies it, since it will generate new token to the recalled request.

Comment: @Chay22 we thought the same thing originally - the difficulty is that if the route isn't defined, the exception handler throws a 404 before any middleware even gets a chance to fire. Is there a way to set a middleware to handle before the exception handler?